# Why is my UITextView reverting to original size in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I have a view controller where when the user clicks in the text view, it will expand the text view and other components all the way to the top of the keyboard. It works as intended for iOS7:

**As soon as user enters view:**
htttp://s29.postimg.org/5fc3l9a5v/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Nov_10_2014_4_56_08.png

**When user clicks inside of text view (or nickname text field):**
htttp://s29.postimg.org/tlmqwdwab/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Nov_10_2014_4_56_13.png

**When user starts typing into the text view:**
htttp://s29.postimg.org/leur4t67n/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Nov_10_2014_4_56_19.png

So that is on the iOS7 simulator in xcode6. This is the proper functionality. The following is iOS8.1 on xcode6 simulator which is giving me grief:

**As soon as user enters view:**
htttp://s3.postimg.org/dp7l6cd6n/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Nov_10_2014_5_02_27.png

**When user clicks inside of text view (or nickname text field):**
htttp://s3.postimg.org/5882vf8hr/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Nov_10_2014_5_02_37.png

**When user starts typing into the text view:**
htttp://s3.postimg.org/mvpvtmif3/i_OS_Simulator_Screen_Shot_Nov_10_2014_5_02_48.png

For some reason as soon as I start typing on the keyboard, the textview and other components like nickname text field, character count label, post button, border lines etc. all revert back in size to what I set them on the storyboard (it doesn't do this on iOS7). Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
    {
        if([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported])
        {
            UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;

            background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^ {
                [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }];

            lastTableViewRowRecent = 0;
            lastTableViewRowPopular = 0;

            [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(221/255.0) blue:(85/255.0) alpha:1.0f]];
            UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                           action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
            tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
            [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                     selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                                         name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                                       object:nil];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                         name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:self.view.window];

            self.textView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;
            self.nicknameTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable;

            self.textView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
            self.nicknameTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

            self.textView.editable = false;
            self.nicknameTextField.enabled = false;
            self.postButton.enabled = false;   
        }
    }
}

-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    int length = textView.text.length;

    if(length > -999)
        self.countLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 300-length];

    if([self.countLabel.text integerValue] <= 0)
        self.countLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    else
        self.countLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if(length > 0)
        self.textViewPlaceholderLabel.hidden = true;

    else
        self.textViewPlaceholderLabel.hidden = false;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        [textView resignFirstResponder];

    if([self.textView.text length] > 299)
        self.textView.text = [self.textView.text substringToIndex:299];

    return true;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"\n"])
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

    if([self.nicknameTextField.text length] > 13)
        self.nicknameTextField.text = [self.nicknameTextField.text substringToIndex:13];

    return true;
}


- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    self.scoreLabel.hidden = true;

    NSDictionary *info = notif.userInfo;
    NSValue *value = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];

    CGRect rawFrame = [value CGRectValue];
    keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:rawFrame fromView:nil];

    [self.borderLineTen setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardFrame.origin.y-2, 320, 2)];
    [self.thickBorderLineThree setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardFrame.origin.y-10, 320, 8)];
    [self.borderLineSeven setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardFrame.origin.y-12, 192, 2)];
    [self.borderLineEight setFrame:CGRectMake(200, keyboardFrame.origin.y-12, 56, 2)];
    [self.borderLineNine setFrame:CGRectMake(264, keyboardFrame.origin.y-12, 56, 2)];
    [self.nicknameTextField setFrame:CGRectMake(10, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 182, 38)];
    [self.leftNicknameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 10, 38)];
    [self.borderLineFourteen setFrame:CGRectMake(190, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 2, 38)];
    [self.borderLineEleven setFrame:CGRectMake(200, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 2, 38)];
    [self.borderLineTwelve setFrame:CGRectMake(254, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 2, 38)];
    [self.borderLineThirteen setFrame:CGRectMake(264, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 2, 38)];
    [self.thickBorderLineFour setFrame:CGRectMake(192, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 8, 40)];
    [self.thickBorderLineFive setFrame:CGRectMake(256, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 8, 40)];
    [self.countLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(200, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 56, 38)];
    [self.postButton setFrame:CGRectMake(264, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 56, 38)];
    [self.borderLineFour setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 192, 2)];
    [self.borderLineFive setFrame:CGRectMake(200, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 56, 2)];
    [self.borderLineSix setFrame:CGRectMake(264, keyboardFrame.origin.y-50, 56, 2)];
    [self.thickBorderLineTwo setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardFrame.origin.y-58, 320, 8)];
    [self.borderLineThree setFrame:CGRectMake(0, keyboardFrame.origin.y-60, 320, 2)];
    [self.textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 86, 320, keyboardFrame.origin.y-86-60)];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    NSLog(@"This doesn't get displayed when I start typing in textview");
    [self.borderLineTen setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 262, 320, 2)];
    [self.thickBorderLineThree setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 254, 320, 8)];
    [self.borderLineSeven setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 252, 192, 2)];
    [self.borderLineEight setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 252, 56, 2)];
    [self.borderLineNine setFrame:CGRectMake(264, 252, 56, 2)];
    [self.nicknameTextField setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 214, 182, 38)];
    [self.leftNicknameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 214, 10, 38)];
    [self.borderLineFourteen setFrame:CGRectMake(190, 216, 2, 38)];
    [self.borderLineEleven setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 216, 2, 38)];
    [self.borderLineTwelve setFrame:CGRectMake(254, 216, 2, 38)];
    [self.borderLineThirteen setFrame:CGRectMake(264, 216, 2, 38)];
    [self.thickBorderLineFour setFrame:CGRectMake(192, 214, 8, 40)];
    [self.thickBorderLineFive setFrame:CGRectMake(256, 214, 8, 40)];
    [self.countLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 214, 56, 38)];
    [self.postButton setFrame:CGRectMake(264, 214, 56, 38)];
    [self.borderLineFour setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 214, 192, 2)];
    [self.borderLineFive setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 214, 56, 2)];
    [self.borderLineSix setFrame:CGRectMake(264, 214, 56, 2)];
    [self.thickBorderLineTwo setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 206, 320, 8)];
    [self.borderLineThree setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 204, 320, 2)];
    [self.textView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 86, 320, 118)];
    self.scoreLabel.hidden = false;
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
    [self.nicknameTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: Auto layout. Learn how to use it.

Comment: I was using it in Xcode5. Obviously there is a difference somewhere..

Comment: I realize that there are new Auto Layout specifics in Xcode6 but this issue seems like it  is something in my code :S

Comment: I was able to disable the keyboard animation by just placing "[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];" in my main view controller. Now I am only baffled by why my text view reverts back to storyboard size even after I change the frame.

Comment: You need to show less code. There is an entire class of code here. It's hard to see which bit of code is actually changing the size of the textview. Delete everything that isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: Also, are you using AutoLayout? I guess you are but just wanted to check.

Comment: Yes I am using Auto Layout. I took out some code.

Comment: Edited with images. Still grieving.

Comment: Still can't figure it out :(